How do I determine thread index in its thread group from inside of the kernel?
I need, for a given thread group, to get each of its member threads sequential index to store some data about each thread from inside of the kernel, I have access to task_struct. Something like "0th thread was created first, 1st thread is created second, ..." would work fine.
One way to distinct threads from one thread group is obviously refer to their process ids, however, process ids are not sequential, while I want to get some sort of identificators that are sequentially ordered one after another (indexes).

Threads are added to the tail of their parent's p->signal->thread_head thread list on creation (code here), so you can simply iterate the threads with for_each_thread(p, t). Assuming you already got ahold of the task_struct for the thread group leader, this is pretty simple:
struct task_struct *leader; // assuming you already have this
struct task_struct *thread;
unsigned thread_idx = 0;

for_each_thread(leader, thread) {
    // ... code here ...
    thread_idx++;
}

Of course, don't forget get_task_struct/put_task_struct where needed.
